# How to find prime factors in a range in php

Tags: php, for-loop, logic

This is a program to find prime factors of a numbers.

Like - Prime factors for number 1125 are `3` and `5`

My Algo this goes way - (and please let me know if it is not correct)

1. Firstly I am finding a square root of the number using `sqrt()`
   function to break the complexity and run time.
2. To find prime numbers in between the range.
3. Lastly to divide these prime numbers with the original number(yet not reached to this step as failing in the second step.

My code which is not working, let me know where exactly I am failing in my logic and code from step 2 and step 3.

**No error thrown but the code is also not outputting anything.**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$number = 6006;

$sqrt_num = (int)sqrt($number);

for($i=2;$i<$sqrt_num;$i++)
{
    for($j=2;$j<=$i-1;$j++)
    {
        if($i%$j==0)
        break;
        if($i==$j) 
            echo $i;
    }   
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14037923/1270996  Possible duplicate

Comment: First, logically, you aren't checking prime numbers, you are checking 'divisible by', secondly, you `break` out of the loop rather than `continue`ing to the next iteration.  Take a look at: http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/03/prime-factoring-with-php/

Comment: You may find your solution here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037688/find-the-highest-prime-number-in-a-given-range

Comment: I tried to add a comment to the solution that you posted, as it could work.  Comment was "Too late to edit my last post, but if `$number` is greater than 1, then 2 will always be a prime number to be included in the list, so you can arbitrarily add `$myarr[] = 2;` after you declare the array."  On a side note, you said you want to find all primes between 1 and the square root of the number chosen, but the first sentence of this question does say looking for prime factors. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm note sure if you want prime factors of a number, or all prime numbers within the range of 1 to sqrt(number), I'll give you some of my code that I wrote a while back and show different implementations:

```
//Check if a number is prime
function isPrime($num, $pf = null)
{
    if(!is_array($pf)) 
    {
        for($i=2;$i<intval(sqrt($num));$i++) {
            if($num % $i==0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        $pfCount = count($pf);
        for($i=0;$i<$pfCount;$i++) {
            if($num % $pf[$i] == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

//Find Prime Factors
function primeFactors($num)
{
    //Record the base
    $base = intval($num/2);
    $pf = array();
    $pn = null;
    for($i=2;$i <= $base;$i++) {
        if(isPrime($i, $pn)) {
            $pn[] = $i;
            while($num % $i == 0)
            {
                $pf[] = $i;
                $num = $num/$i;
            }
        }
    }
    return $pf;
}
```

From that, to get the prime factors, just use `$myarr = primeFactors($number);` (and you can see the logic used to recreate your own. ^^)

If you want all prime numbers in the range:

```
for($i=1;$i<$sqrt_num;$i++) {
    if(isPrime($i)) {
        $myarr[] = $i;
    }
}
```

I do want to note the use of `$pf` in `isPrime`, as it is the sieve to reduce the processing time of finding out if a number is prime based on the prime factors already processed.

Comment: Actually my code was a sub part..I was looking for prime factors of a number and that number is very large, so I break down that number by my sqrt() return value and then looking for prime numbers from 1 to sqrt_number.....and the thing was I was lost in finding prime number from 2 to sqrt_number

Comment: @swapnesh ahh, ok! ^^  For that, you need to know that you'd have to go to `$number/2`, as `sqrt($number)` is too small.  For an example, the number `102012` as the prime factors of `2,2,3,8501`, and stopping at the `sqrt($number)` would never give you the `8501` factor. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Finding prime numbers is a common problem in most programming languages. First, take a look on [number is prime](http://icdif.com/computing/2011/09/15/check-number-prime-number/). You can use the [`gmp_nextprime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-nextprime.php) function.

Comment: He's actually looking for prime factors.

Comment: For prime factor take a look on http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/03/prime-factoring-with-php/

Comment: @user1929959 Thanks for the link..but actually I am more interested in finding bug in my own code..once not found I from my side ask for the logical help here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$namber = 1122676330;
$text = $namber.'=';
$time_start = microtime(1);

for($i=2; $i<=$namber; $i++ ){
    if($namber % $i == 0){
        $namber = $namber / $i;
        $text .= $i. '  ';
        $i--;
    }
    if($namber == 1){
            echo 'ok';
        }
}

$time_end = microtime(1);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<br><br>$text<br><br> $time seconds\n";
```

Comment: This may answer the question (I'm not a PHP guy), but some explaining as to WHY it works with comments and text would be nice. Now it's just a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php class on [PrimeModule](https://github.com/danog/PrimeModule)

PHP Prime module capable of doing prime factorization of huge numbers very quickly.

link:
https://github.com/danog/PrimeModule